TeXLive distribution TeXworks editor *does not start*
Troubleshooting TeXLive has been insufferable for me for the past week. I am at a loss. I am on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine. I have completely gutted this system of all previous failed TeX distribution installs. I install privately only to my user because this is a university machine and i dont have admin rights.  I finally got it to the point where TeXLive installs without any permissions issues (e.g. "cannot unlink dirX..."; "permission denied at dirY...") and i installed the TeXLive teTax distribution (larger than medium) and made SURE to check that the TeXworks frontend is installed. The install seemed to work without issue. The editor does not run.  Has anyone encountered this before??

If you go to the Command Prompt, navigate to the folder where TeXworks is installed, and type the name of the executable followed by enter, do you get any errors or warnings in the command prompt output?
